# Bootstrap column won't center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to make a column within my Bootstrap structure center --
[image]

I've tried adding -

```
    .col-md-3 {
    width:20%;
    display:block;
```

as well as -

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

but without any luck. I've also tried clearing the float ('clear:both') but it made all the images jumbled.

What am I doing wrong? Here is [my site](http://tinyurl.com/ofpv3xo)

Answer (score 1):

.col-md-3 should do it by default, but if you're overriding then for 4 items in a row you want it to be:  **width:25%;**

Try that

Comment: Having had a look at your site, I made your class .portfolio-item with width:25% and the UL under them with no padding, ie: .portfolio-item ul {padding: 0;} - and it worked out

Comment: Ah I'm so stupid, how did I miss that... is there any way to make the column narrower?

Comment: Sure there is, you could make the container narrower, something like: 
.container {
width: 950px;
}
Else you could toy with offsets

Comment: Hmm yeah I did that but it's throwing the alignment of my thumbnails off

Comment: Had a quick look again, for your class container-releases, try: .container-releases{margin: 0 auto;width: 800px;}

Comment: yeah the alignment is still off.. so weird ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use  center tag infront of divs to center them.

Heres an example:

```
<center>
<div class="col-md-3>
your contents
</div>
</center>
```

Thanks